# prestashop : How to get value of attribute

Tags: php, prestashop

I have products with small and medium size. And I can take the quantity of products with this code. " $product->quantity " . But I want to get quantity of Small size and Medium Size seperately. How to write code to get these values ? Pls help me.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the code is

> {$product.quantity}

but, if you are referring to different products combinations ( small and medium size ) you should get the combinations of the products first, I think is this code:

> $product->getAttributeCombinaisons($params['cookie']->id_lang);

good luck ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop 1.5 :

```
 $product->getAttributeCombinaisons($params['cookie']->id_lang);
```

getAttributeCombinaisons is deprecated with Prestashop 1.6

Use instead :

```
getAttributeCombinations
```